# Trouble with comparing 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I keep getting a `false` boolean value from the following comparison:

```
public boolean getHz1() {
    return board[0][0] == board[0][1] 
           && board[0][1] == board[0][2] 
           && board[0][0] != null 
           && board[0][1] != null 
           && board[0][2] != null;
 }
```

The relevant call in the driver class is:

```
do {
        System.out.println("Your turn: ");
        g1.play(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt(), s.next());
        System.out.println(g1.getHz1());
} while (g1.getHz1() == false)
```

The "play" method takes 2 integers and a string value to put in the array, in this case "x".  When I print out the `board[0][0]`, `board[0][1]` and `board[0][2]`, all contain the string "x", but `getHz1` still returns `false`.

Comment: Can you try with equals method instead of comparing values with == operator

Comment: (1) You usually need to use `equals` instead of `==` to compare String values.  (2) You should do the null checks before the equality checks, not the other way round, or you risk getting null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should compare objects using the `equals` method instead of `==`.

```
public boolean getHz1() {
    return board[0][0] != null 
           && board[0][1] != null 
           && board[0][2] != null
           && board[0][0].equals(board[0][1]) 
           && board[0][1].equals(board[0][2]);
}
```

`==` is only `true` if two objects have the same pointer.

Comment: This is duplicate as stated in comments.

Comment: That works. I looked at the compare string page but for some reason the fact that the actual array values were strings escaped me.

Comment: why does != work in this case?  should it not be !board[0][1].equals(null)?

Comment: because you are testing if the instance `board[0][0]` is not referencing to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

"==" is only used for primitive types (ints, booleans, etc.). A string is an object, so using == is checking the object reference (if String 1 is the same object as String 2). When comparing strings, you need to use .equals(), which tests for equal values.

Comment: Boolean is a class, boolean is a primitive type ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to use `.equals` for objects (e.g., String, HashMap, anything that is created with `new`), and the `==` operator for native datatypes (e.g., `int`, `long`, `char`, etc.).  The warning, however, is that `.equals` is a function *on an object*, so you first need to make sure the object is not null.  Hence this pattern:

```
if ( obj != null && obj.someFunction() )
```

When comparing objects, you can also let the `.equals` function do the null check for you:

```
SomeObject goodObj = new SomeObject();
SomeObject badObj = null;

if ( goodObj.equals( badObj ) )  // should work properly, no matter the state of badObj
```

In your case, you need to check that your objects are not null **first**, and then compare the objects appropriately with .equals:

```
public boolean getHz1() {
    return (
        (null == board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2])
     || (null != board[0][0] && board[0][0].equals(board[0][1]) && board[0][0].equals(board[0][2]))
    );
}
```

Presumably, if they're all null, they're also all equivalent, hence the first line.  The next line checks the only other way they could be equal (they're all not null, but arbitrarily check the first cell for nullness).

Comment: The following works well:
public boolean getHz1() {
  return board[0][0] != null && board[0][1] != null && board[0][2] != null && board[0][0].equals(board[0][1])
    && board[0][1].equals(board[0][2]);